# Store SSH command history on local machine

Tags: shell, ssh, command-history, remote

I often use SSH to connect to ARM machine which reboots regularly and doesn't have any persistent memory to store `sh` command history. Is there a way to store such history on my local machine so it could be accessible by `^R` and `up`/`down` when connected to the remote? Or is there another workaround to such problem besides storing most useful commands in a notepad? :)

Comment: What shell do you use on the ARM machine? It probably can be configured to store a history file to the ramfs or whatever non-persistent filesystem the machine is using. Then, replace your remote `exit` comannd by an alias, which copies that history file to your host before exiting and replace your `ssh` call by a copying of the saved file back to the machine before actually connecting.

Comment: @Philippos pure `sh` (not `bash`) wrapped into `BusyBox 1.20.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is the [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) program, dating from 1999,  which should be available on your home machine in a package of the same name. It uses the GNU **readline** library to front-end any command with a re-usable history that is saved by default in a file `~/.`*command*`_history`, so in your case it should end up in `~/.ssh_history` if you do:

```
rlwrap ssh remote
```

(If you want to test this to a remote running an application or shell that already has readline built-in, you will need to disable the remote readline. For example with a remote bash do: `rlwrap ssh remote bash --noediting` to see it working.)

Comment: This looks like a great solution with a single downside: if I use `rlwrap ssh user@ip sh --noediting` I do not get the shell "prefix" (`~/dir $ _` one), just an empty line. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't need this option. I was using it because I don't have a remote that runs a busybox sh so was pretending with a remote bash. The problem seems to be a conflict between the remote using readline and so putting the terminal in raw mode, and rlwrap trying to do the same. What might work is to ask ssh to not provide a pty (use `-T`), but then you will lose job control on the remote.

Comment: `-T` in pure `ssh` causes the same prompt loss, and in `rlwrap ssh` it doesn't change anything. Also autompletion doesn't work and `^C` and `^Z` are sent to host machine. Apparently this tool causes more problems than it solves :(

Comment: It seems `rlwrap -a ssh remote` should allow rlwrap to handle the problem you have, without resorting to `--noediting` in your shell.

Comment: Yes, the `-a` option fixes prompt. The autocompletion seems unfixable without direct specifying of completion file, from what I've googled. It is nice to know that there is atleast formal solution to my problem, even with its downsides.